# Changing individual parameters for all objects of the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I asked a smilier question before, but generalized it too much to get an helpful answer. I am quite new to Python, pygame and programming in general. I want to make a game with python, in which you control a player through a dungeon. I already created a the player and animated it. I also set the map bigger than the game window and achieved a moving background to create kind of an "exploring"-effect. In case my player gets to borders inside the game window, the larger background image is moving the opposite direction as the player with the same value of his speed. Now I created a class Obstacle() and wanted to place on object of this class on my map to add collision later. Obviously the obstacle object should stay on its position on the map background, means, moving with it. Its no big problem to transform the background moving if-statements to obstacle moving ones but I plan to create a lot more obstacles and don't want to add this bunch of if-statements for every single one. does anyone here has an idea how I can realize my plan? Cause I am new to programming I am thankful for every other tip in relation to my programming style. Here is my whole code. Thank you in advance.

```
    import pygame
import pygame.event
pygame.init()

# sets the width and hight of the window
window_width = 800
window_height = 600

# sets the area, the hero is allowed to move without changing background
window_visible_x = 150
window_visible_y = 150

# creates the window and gives it a title
window = pygame.display.set_mode((window_width, window_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Dungeon")

# sets images or creates a list of images for animation
hero_image_walking_right = [pygame.image.load(r"/Users/myname123/Documents/Python Docs/Dungeon/pics_ready/png/hero_right_1.png"), pygame.image.load(r"/Users/myname123/Documents/Python Docs/Dungeon/pics_ready/png/hero_right_2.png"), pygame.image.load(r"/Users/myname123/Documents/Python Docs/Dungeon/pics_ready/png/hero_right_3.png"), pygame.image.load(r"/Users/myname123/Documents/Python Docs/Dungeon/pics_ready/png/hero_right_4.png"), pygame.image.load(r"/Users/myname123/Documents/Python Docs/Dungeon/pics_ready/png/hero_right_3.png"), pygame.image.load(r"/Users/myname123/Documents/Python Docs/Dungeon/pics_ready/png/hero_right_2.png")]
hero_image_walking_left = [pygame.image.load(r"/Users/myname123/Documents/Python Docs/Dungeon/pics_ready/png/hero_left_1.png"), pygame.image.load(r"/Users/myname123/Documents/Python Docs/Dungeon/pics_ready/png/hero_left_2.png"), pygame.image.load(r"/Users/myname123/Documents/Python Docs/Dungeon/pics_ready/png/hero_left_3.png"), pygame.image.load(r"/Users/myname123/Documents/Python Docs/Dungeon/pics_ready/png/hero_left_4.png"), pygame.image.load(r"/Users/myname123/Documents/Python Docs/Dungeon/pics_ready/png/hero_left_3.png"), pygame.image.load(r"/Users/myname123/Documents/Python Docs/Dungeon/pics_ready/png/hero_left_2.png")]
hero_image_facing_right = pygame.image.load(r"/Users/myname123/Documents/Python Docs/Dungeon/pics_ready/png/hero_facing_right.png")
hero_image_facing_left = pygame.image.load(r"/Users/myname123/Documents/Python Docs/Dungeon/pics_ready/png/hero_facing_left.png")
background_image = pygame.image.load(r"/Users/myname123/Documents/Python Docs/Dungeon/pics_ready/png/test_background.png")
obstacle_1_image = pygame.image.load(r"/Users/myname123/Documents/Python Docs/Dungeon/pics_ready/png/obstacle_1.png")

# creates a clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# redrawas the whole window every tick
def redraw_window():

    # sets background
    window.blit(background_image, (background.x, background.y))

    # sets obstacle
    window.blit(obstacle_1_image, (obstacle_1.x, obstacle_1.y))

    # sets walk counter for animation to 0 in case it reaches 60
    if hero.walk_count + 1 >= 60:
        hero.walk_count = 0

    # animates the hero while moving
    if hero.walking_left:
        window.blit(hero_image_walking_left[hero.walk_count//10], (hero.x, hero.y))
        hero.walk_count += 1

    elif hero.walking_right:
        window.blit(hero_image_walking_right[hero.walk_count//10], (hero.x, hero.y))
        hero.walk_count += 1

    elif hero.walking_up:
        if hero.facing_left:
            window.blit(hero_image_walking_left[hero.walk_count//10], (hero.x, hero.y))
            hero.walk_count += 1
        elif hero.facing_right:
            window.blit(hero_image_walking_right[hero.walk_count//10], (hero.x, hero.y))
            hero.walk_count += 1

    elif hero.walking_down:
        if hero.facing_left:
            window.blit(hero_image_walking_left[hero.walk_count//10], (hero.x, hero.y))
            hero.walk_count += 1
        elif hero.facing_right:
            window.blit(hero_image_walking_right[hero.walk_count//10], (hero.x, hero.y))
            hero.walk_count += 1


    # sets a standing picture for hero while not moving depneding on last moved direction
    else:
        if hero.facing_left:
            window.blit(hero_image_facing_left, (hero.x, hero.y))
        else:
            window.blit(hero_image_facing_right, (hero.x, hero.y))

    hero.hitbox = (hero.x, hero.y, hero.width, hero.height)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), hero.hitbox, 2)
    obstacle_1.hitbox = (obstacle_1.x, obstacle_1.y, obstacle_1.width, obstacle_1.height)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), obstacle_1.hitbox, 2)
    print(background.x, background.y)

    # updates the window
    pygame.display.update()

def moving_hero():
    # start of testing for inputs
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a] or keys[pygame.K_d] or keys[pygame.K_w] or keys[pygame.K_s]:
        if keys[pygame.K_a] and hero.x > window_visible_x - hero.width:
            hero.x -= hero.velocity
            hero.walking_left = True
            hero.walking_right = False
            hero.walinkg_up = False
            hero.walking_down = False
            hero.facing_left = True
            hero.facing_right = False
        elif keys[pygame.K_a] and hero.x <= window_visible_x - hero.width and background.x < 0:
                background.x += hero.velocity
                Obstacle.x += hero.velocity

        if keys[pygame.K_d] and hero.x < window_width - window_visible_x:
            hero.x += hero.velocity
            hero.walking_left = False
            hero.walking_right = True
            hero.walinkg_up = False
            hero.walking_down = False
            hero.facing_left = False
            hero.facing_right = True
        elif keys[pygame.K_d] and hero.x >= window_width - window_visible_x and background.x > window_width - background.width:
                background.x -= hero.velocity
                Obstacle.x -= hero.velocity

        if keys[pygame.K_w] and hero.y > window_visible_y - hero.height:
            hero.y -= hero.velocity
            hero.walking_left = False
            hero.walking_right = False
            hero.walking_up = True
            hero.walking_down = False
        elif keys[pygame.K_w] and hero.y <= window_visible_y - hero.height and background.y < 0:
            background.y += hero.velocity
            Obstacle.y += hero.velocity

        if keys[pygame.K_s] and hero.y < window_height - window_visible_y:
            hero.y += hero.velocity
            hero.walking_left = False
            hero.walking_right = False
            hero.walinkg_up = False
            hero.walking_down = True
        elif keys[pygame.K_s] and hero.y >= window_height - window_visible_y and background.y > window_height - background.heigth:
            background.y -= hero.velocity
            Obstacle.y -= hero.velocity

    else:
        hero.walking_left = False
        hero.walking_right = False
        hero.walking_up = False
        hero.walking_down = False
        hero.walk_count = 0



# class Living for all moveable objects. Every object is given a x- and y- coordiante, a width and a height, health and velocity as well as a parameter to indicat in which directions its moving and facing
class Living():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, health, velocity):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.health = health
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.walk_count = 0
        self.walking_left = False
        self.walking_right = False
        self.walking_up = False
        self.walking_down = False
        self.facing_left = False
        self.facing_right = True
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, 64, 64)

# class Background for different backgrounds. Every background is given a x- and y- coordinate as well as a width and height
class Background():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.heigth = height

class Obstacle():

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x
        self.y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)


# creates a objects of class Living
hero = Living(200, 200, 64, 64, 100, 3)

# creates objects of class Background
background = Background(0, 0, 2000, 2000)

# creates an obstacle of class Obstacle
obstacle_1 = Obstacle(500, 500, 50, 60)

# run variable is set to True
run = True

# as long as run = True the following things are getting executet every clock tick
while run:

    # sets clock tick
    clock.tick(60)

    # allows the user to close the game by pressing the X button above the gamewindow
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    moving_hero()

    redraw_window()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I know you want an answer to this question specifically, but my recommendation is that you find a free online course for learning Python a bit better so you can apply things to your game. Udacity has quite a few free courses that are good for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what you want to do exactly. 
But you could add all your obstacles to a list, a dict or some iterable and iterate over it to change their attributes.

You could also use a class variable and properties like so:

```
class Obstacle:
    reference_x = 0

    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.reference_x + self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        self._x = x
```

If you test it:

```
a = Obstacle(1)
print(a.x)
>> 1
Obstacle.reference_x = 12
print(a.x)
>> 13
```

#### Explanation

*reference_x* is a class attribute. It is accessible from all the instance of the class and also from the class object itself, and it is the same for every instance of the class.

Properties allow you to define the way the attribute is accessed, changed or deleted.
So here I use a "private" attribute *_x* ( _ being a common convention to identify attributes as private, as no such thing actually exist in python).
Then I define a property *x* with a *getter* that return `self.reference_x + self._x` . This function is called every-time you try to access the variable, hence why it works: when you change reference_x and call the attribute x again, it computes x with the new value of reference_x. I also define a setter to make sure the user changes x relatively to reference_x (by changing _x)

Bear in mind that `self.reference_x + self._x` is done every time you want to access the x attribute, even if reference_x does not change. It could a  problem if you are really really desperate about performance.

I would advise you to have a look at the free python classes online to for clearer and deeper explanation about properties and python objects.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I needed. can you explain what did please?

Comment: I will add some explanation to the answer. If this is the answer to your question then fell free to mark it as accepted